# How would I create a real-time chat using PHP, AJAX and AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ajax, chat

Is there any simple way to make a real-time private messaging website without having to use node.js & socket.io?

I'm not asking for the code, I just want to get some sort of starting point since I really have no idea how to do it.

Comment: My answer contains some links that may help you to create a Real Time Chat using Ajax, this is pretty simple to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Ajax](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiBpvbZ5oHUAhWmIcAKHRanCnIQFggnMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fjquery.ajax%2F&usg=AFQjCNET1WrVqP-BPFBEQY1R7V6crOtd1w&sig2=w8-gg90Tanq5uTheRHFOZg) Jquery & HTML to make a chat.

Here is one I found on Github, this might help you to learn how to make one using these coding langugaes.

Github link: https://github.com/Frug/AJAX-Chat

Answer (score 1):

Why do not you want to use sockets? You will be obliged to make requests every second(you say real-time chat) and it will be hard for the sever. How about if more than 100, 1000 or 5000 users are chating ?

You better use socket.io because it avoids this kind of overloading

Comment: The truth is that I don't really know much about sockets, and to be honest I feel like it would take a pretty long time to get everything setup. But now that you mention it I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Writing a chat application with popular web applications stacks like LAMP (PHP) has traditionally been very hard. It involves polling the server for changes, keeping track of timestamps, and it’s a lot slower than it should be.

Sockets have traditionally been the solution around which most realtime chat systems are architected, providing a bi-directional communication channel between a client and a server.

This means that the server can push messages to clients. Whenever you write a chat message, the idea is that the server will get it and push it to all other connected clients.